# XSLT 1.0 to retrieve or parse a specific value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an issue with the XSLT below. I need help to fix my transformation. I am using XSLT 1.0. Input can be 120KVA or 120MVA or 120.0KVA or 120.0KV. Output i want to parse into 3 parts. i.e.

```
<tns:ratedApparentPower>
          <tns:unitSymbolUnit>VA</tns:unitSymbolUnit>
          <tns:multiplier>K</tns:multiplier>
          <tns:floatValue>120.0</tns:floatValue>
 </tns:ratedApparentPower>
```

My current Transformation is:

```
   <tns:ratedApparentPower>
      <tns:unitSymbolUnit>VA</tns:unitSymbolUnit>
      <tns:multiplier>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(//ns0:ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_ITEM[ns0:NAME='DISTXFR']/ns0:ATTRIBUTES/ns0:ATTRIBUTES_ITEM[ns0:NAME='KVA']/ns0:VALUE,'1234567890', ''),1,1)" />
      </tns:multiplier>
      <tns:floatValue>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//ns0:ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_ITEM[ns0:NAME='DISTXFR']/ns0:ATTRIBUTES/ns0:ATTRIBUTES_ITEM[ns0:NAME='KVA']/ns0:VALUE,substring(translate(//ns0:ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_ITEM[ns0:NAME='DISTXFR']/ns0:ATTRIBUTES/ns0:ATTRIBUTES_ITEM[ns0:NAME='KVA']/ns0:VALUE,'1234567890', ''),1,1))" />
      </tns:floatValue>
   </tns:ratedApparentPower>
</xsl:if>
```

Generated O/P:

```
<tns:ratedApparentPower>
          <tns:unitSymbolUnit>VA</tns:unitSymbolUnit>
          <tns:multiplier>.</tns:multiplier>
          <tns:floatValue>120</tns:floatValue>
 </tns:ratedApparentPower>
```

My doubts are:

1. How to get `<tns:unitSymbolUnit>VA</tns:unitSymbolUnit>`? Currently, I am hardcoding it. But it can be V or VA or any other value
2. How to get multiplier? With my current logic I  get as `<tns:multiplier>.</tns:multiplier>` when I have 120.0 it works fine.
3. With my current logic I get `<tns:floatValue>120</tns:floatValue>` instead of 120.0.
4. Is there any way I can shorten the path (`//ns0:ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_ITEM[ns0:NAME='DISTXFR']/ns0:ATTRIBUTES/ns0:ATTRIBUTES_ITEM[ns0:NAME='KVA']/ns0:VALUE`) by assigning it to some variable instead of using whole path every time?

Michael I edited your template belwo to match my requiremnts and usinga callTemplate but receive empty response

```
<xsl:template name="convertFloatValues">
    <xsl:param name="floatValue1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="unit" select="translate($floatValue1, '0123456789.', '')"/>
    <unitSymbolUnit>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($unit, 2)"/>
    </unitSymbolUnit>
    <multiplier>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($unit, 1 , 1)"/>
    </multiplier>
    <floatValue>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $unit)"/>
    </floatValue>
  </xsl:template>
```

Call Template example . Not sure what I am missing. Can you please help me.

```
 <tns:ratedApparentPower>
                        <xsl:call-template name="convertFloatValues">
                          <xsl:with-param name="floatValue1" select="/ns0:OutputParameters/ns0:XXJEAM_ASSET_SEARCH_PKG-24GETAS/ns0:ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS/ns0:ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_ITEM[ns0:NAME='DISTXFR']/ns0:ATTRIBUTES/ns0:ATTRIBUTES_ITEM[ns0:NAME='KVA']/ns0:VALUE"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </tns:ratedApparentPower>
```

Input:

```
<OutputParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns="*****">
  <XXJEAM_ASSET_SEARCH_PKG-24GETAS>
      <ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_ITEM>
        <NAME>DISTXFR</NAME>
        <ATTRIBUTES>
          <ATTRIBUTES_ITEM>
            <COLUMN_NAME>C_ATTRIBUTE3</COLUMN_NAME>
            <NAME>Volt</NAME>
            <VALUE>500</VALUE>
          </ATTRIBUTES_ITEM>
          <ATTRIBUTES_ITEM>
            <COLUMN_NAME>C_ATTRIBUTE4</COLUMN_NAME>
            <NAME>KVA</NAME>
            <VALUE>500.0KVA</VALUE>
          </ATTRIBUTES_ITEM>
         </ATTRIBUTES>
      </ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS_ITEM>

  </XXJEAM_ASSET_SEARCH_PKG-24GETAS>

</OutputParameters>
```

Comment: Your logic states: multiplier is _"the first character not been a digit"_, float value is everything before multipliar. Following that, unit symbol should be everything after multiplier. Multiplier would be better defined with _"the firs character not been a digit or dot"_: `substring(translate($value, '1234567890.', ''), 1, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>20KVA</item>
    <item>120MVA</item>
    <item>120.0KVA</item>
    <item>120.0KV</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:variable name="unit" select="translate(., '0123456789.', '')" />
            <ratedApparentPower>
                <unitSymbolUnit>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($unit, 2)" />
                </unitSymbolUnit>
                <multiplier>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($unit, 1 , 1)" />
                </multiplier>
                <floatValue>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $unit)" />
                </floatValue>
            </ratedApparentPower>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <ratedApparentPower>
    <unitSymbolUnit>VA</unitSymbolUnit>
    <multiplier>K</multiplier>
    <floatValue>20</floatValue>
  </ratedApparentPower>
  <ratedApparentPower>
    <unitSymbolUnit>VA</unitSymbolUnit>
    <multiplier>M</multiplier>
    <floatValue>120</floatValue>
  </ratedApparentPower>
  <ratedApparentPower>
    <unitSymbolUnit>VA</unitSymbolUnit>
    <multiplier>K</multiplier>
    <floatValue>120.0</floatValue>
  </ratedApparentPower>
  <ratedApparentPower>
    <unitSymbolUnit>V</unitSymbolUnit>
    <multiplier>K</multiplier>
    <floatValue>120.0</floatValue>
  </ratedApparentPower>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am trying to do a xsl-call template. Because I have to use the same logic at 42 different places. So i thought call template will be simple So i edited your template little to mach my requirements. But when i do a call i receive empty response. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Adding my cod to the question

Comment: Please edit your question again and show an example of the input - see [mcve].

Comment: @Michael--Added teh input. thanks so much Really appreciated

Comment: I am afraid I cannot reproduce your problem from the code snippets you have posted. You can see how it can work here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGM

Comment: Thanks So much Michael. You are awesome. Sorry for late reply. I got busy with few other things. But I tried and fixed few things in my xpath on my end and this worked